# CIGaussianBlur and CIAffineClamp on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-image

I am trying to blur an image using CoreImage on iOS 6 without having a noticeable black border. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAffineClamp) states that using a CIAffineClamp filter can achieve this but I'm not able to get an output image from the filter. Here's what I tried, but unfortunately an empty image is created when I access the [clampFilter outputImage]. If I only perform the blur an image is produced, but with the dark inset border.

```
CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:self.CGImage];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

CIFilter *clampFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineClamp"];
[clampFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[clampFilter setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&transform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)] forKey:@"inputTransform"];

CIImage *outputImage = [clampFilter outputImage];

CIFilter *blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"
     keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, outputImage, @"inputRadius", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:radius], nil];

outputImage = [blurFilter outputImage];

CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *blurredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The CIAffineClamp filter is setting your extent as infinite, which then confounds your context.  Try saving off the pre-clamp extent CGRect, and then supplying that to the context initializer.

Comment: The contextRect was the issue. I actually fixed it by changing this line to use the inputImage extent when creating the CGImage at the end:

`CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:inputImage.extent];`