# Saving PHAsset with CIGaussianBlur and CIAffineClamp

Tags: ios, objective-c, cifilter, phasset

First of all, I asked my senior and even our boss in the office, but they are not replying to my question. - **HOW TO SAVE A PHASSET WITH TWO FILTERS APPLIED AT THE SAME TIME?**

I have a project that uses PHAssets for editing metadata of the assets (photos/videos). Now, I can modify the images by applying tags and filters. See this example: http://dev.classmethod.jp/references/ios8-photo-kit-4/

I recently had a problem about extra border generated by CIGaussianBlur and I learned that I have to have CIAffineClamp filter to fix the problem: [CIGaussianBlur and CIAffineClamp on iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910625/cigaussianblur-and-ciaffineclamp-on-ios-6)

Unfortunately, I don't know how to save the PHAsset or modify the PHAsset when there are two filters that I need to apply. Here's my code in applying the two filters:

```
    // G: If Blur, then adjust first the frame before applying blur!
    if ([filterName isEqualToString:@"CIGaussianBlur"])
    {
        [filter setValue:inputImageForFilter forKey:@"inputImage"];
        CGFloat blurLevel = 20.0f;
        [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:blurLevel] forKey:@"inputRadius"];

        CIImage* filterInputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:originalImage.CGImage];
        CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:filterName];

        CIFilter *clampFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineClamp"];
        [clampFilter setDefaults];
        [clampFilter setValue:filterInputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

        [filter setValue:clampFilter.outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        [filter setValue:@10.0f forKey:@"inputRadius"];

        CIImage* filterOutputImage = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

        CGImageRef createdImage = [context createCGImage:filterOutputImage fromRect:[filterInputImage extent]];
        UIImage* outputImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:createdImage];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            strongSelf.capturedImageView.image = outputImage;
            strongSelf.capturedImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [strongSelf.capturedImageView layoutSubviews];
        });

        strongSelf.appliedFilter.filterName = filterName;
        strongSelf.appliedFilter.editingInput = contentEditingInput;
        strongSelf.appliedFilter.outputImage = filterOutputImage;

        CGImageRelease(createdImage);
        createdImage = nil;
    }
```

And here's my code in saving the data:

```
- (void)doneButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    // G: Handle Nil FilterName for Fixing Crash :)
    if (self.appliedFilter.filterName == nil) {
        // G: just pop to the view controller next to root, which is the Camera View Controller in Photo Mode.
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[1] animated:YES];
    }

    else{
        // Create a PHAdjustmentData object that describes the filter that was applied.
        PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc] initWithFormatIdentifier:AdjustmentFormatIdentifier formatVersion:@"1.0" data:[self.appliedFilter.filterName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        PHAdjustmentData *affineClamp = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc] initWithFormatIdentifier:AdjustmentFormatIdentifier formatVersion:@"1.0" data:[@"CIAffineClamp" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        /*
         Create a PHContentEditingOutput object and write a JPEG representation
         of the filtered object to the renderedContentURL.
         */
        PHContentEditingOutput *contentEditingOutput = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc] initWithContentEditingInput:self.appliedFilter.editingInput];
        NSData *jpegData = [self.appliedFilter.outputImage aapl_jpegRepresentationWithCompressionQuality:0.9f];
        [jpegData writeToURL:[contentEditingOutput renderedContentURL] atomically:YES];
        [contentEditingOutput setAdjustmentData:adjustmentData];

        if ([self.appliedFilter.filterName isEqualToString:@"CIGaussianBlur"]) {
            [contentEditingOutput setAdjustmentData:affineClamp];
        }

        // Ask the shared PHPhotoLinrary to perform the changes.
        [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            PHAssetChangeRequest *request = [PHAssetChangeRequest changeRequestForAsset:self.photo.asset];
            request.contentEditingOutput = contentEditingOutput;
        } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }
        }];

        // G: just pop to the view controller next to root, which is the Camera View Controller in Photo Mode.
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[1] animated:YES];

    }

}
```

Again, the saving the data part code works very well if I only have 1 filter to apply. So again, my problem is how to adjust the data when there are two filters to apply. Thank you so much. I believe my question is so clear. ;) Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know how you can redeclare *filter without getting an error (it must first be declared outside of your control structure, and then you redeclare it within).

Here is a simple routine that will apply your blur and return an image with the extents you're looking for.

```
- (CIImage*)blurImage:(CIImage*)sourceImage withRadius:(NSNumber*)blurRadius {

    CGRect originalExtent = sourceImage.extent;

    CIImage *clampedImaged = [sourceImage imageByClampingToExtent];

    CIImage *blurredImage = [clampedImaged imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIGaussianBlur" withInputParameters:@{@"inputRadius" : blurRadius}];

    return [blurredImage imageByCroppingToRect:originalExtent];
}
```

Otherwise, I can't tell you what originalImage or inputImageForFilter are referring to, so it's difficult to suggest where the hangup is. You could debug this line by line and use Xcode's peek function (the eyeball icon) to ensure that the CIImage objects that are generated from each filter are what you'd expect.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yeah, I made a mistake by making a new CIFilter object. Anyway, what I want to know is how to save the image as PHAsset.

Comment: Ok, so where is your save routine breaking down?

Comment: The saving part is in my doneButtonAction method. Like what I've said, that method works fine when I am only applying 1 filter at a time. For example: Posterize Filter. It prompts the user if he/she wants to MODIFY the photo upon calling that method. However, when I'm applying blur with CIAffineClamp, it gives me this error in completion handler: — Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with your save routine and more to do with how you're using your filters. I mean, chain two simple filters together (like CIColorControls and CIColorInvert) and see what happens.